# Evaluating $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\arctan(n+2)-\arctan(n)}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

The above is the telescoping series and the terms cancel but I'm left with $-\arctan(1)$ which is equal to $-\pi \over 4$ which is not correct.

Comment: $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \arctan (n+2) \neq 0$.

Answer (score 8):

There are more terms surviving after telescoping. Namely, we are left with 
\begin{align}\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \Bigl(\arctan (n+1) + \arctan n - \arctan 1 - \arctan 0\Bigr) = \frac{ \pi}{2} +\frac{ \pi}{2} -\frac{ \pi}{4}-0 =\frac{ 3\pi}{4}.
\end{align}

Comment: My mistake - sorry about that! Thanks for the correction, and +1 for a nice answer.

Comment: @AWertheim Thanks and sorry if I was too sharp, no offence was meant.

Comment: How did you get the terms arctan(n+1) and arctan(n) because I only got the last two terms?

Comment: @user90219 Just write a finite sum, say, $\sum_{n=0}^{5}$ and observe how different terms cancel out and what remains.

Answer (score 0):

finding a few terms

arctan (2) - arctan(0) + arctan(3 )- arctan(1) + .............arctan (∞) +arctan( ∞ +1)

» 2arctan( ∞)  -arctan(1)

»  3π/4